# Xampp localhost/phpmyadmin error

Tags: php

Every time I try to access my localhost/phpmyadmin it gives me this error --->
Error
MySQL said:

## 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Please I really need your help, I'm clueless. Below is my config.inc.php file
Thanks a lot for your help!

```
<?php
/*
* This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
* cookie
*/
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; 

/*
*Servers configuration
*/
$i = 0;

/*
* First server
*/
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '**********'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';

/*
* End of servers configuration
*/

?>
```

Comment: Is the Mysql service running on your server?

Comment: No, it stops after about 3 secs every time I start it. Any suggestions on what I could do?

Comment: It doesn't seem like an issue with phpMyAdmin, check your MySQL logs (xampp\mysql\data\mysql_error.log) or try running mysql.exe in the command line and check what it says.

Comment: for some reason, I can't find mysql.exe on my computer, was i suppose to install mysql separately from xampp??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a linux system, you should add the following to your config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock';
    or
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

On a windows system,

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = "c:/tmp/mysql.sock"
```

The same changes must be reflected in your xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini file as well.

Comment: Did you change it in the my.ini file as well?

Comment: I can't find the my.ini file, is it in the same directory??

Comment: You might be better off completely removing XAMPP, including installed directories and reinstalling it then, rather than finding the error. Make sure you have no other MySQL instances running.

Comment: ok, I'll give that a try. Pls how can I check if there is any other MySQL instance running??

Comment: It might have been installed in the past and lying dormant :)
Just check your installed programs and your Program Files directory.

Comment: kk, tnx a lot. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: I just found microsoft sql server compact edition(ENU) on my pc, should I uninstall it?? it has been there since i bought the pc

Comment: No. Not necessary. That runs on a different port.

Comment: I just re-installed it, it's giving me a new error :( "phpMyAdmin was unable to read your configuration file!
This might happen if PHP finds a parse error in it or PHP cannot find the file."

Answer (score 1):

From the [Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html):
The error (2002) Can't connect to ... normally means that there is no MySQL server running on the system or that you are using an incorrect Unix socket file name or TCP/IP port number when trying to connect to the server. You should also check that the TCP/IP port you are using has not been blocked by a firewall or port blocking service.

Answer (score 0):

I too got same error when i tried to open phpmyadmin, i removed mecafee from my system then i restarted the system, from then it was working fine, may be mecafee(anit virus) was the problem... Hope it works for you...